# Threejs: Shadow appearing as box shape

Tags: three.js

I set up a simple glb viewer with three.js. The model casts and accepts shadows. The problem is that dark boxes appear once I set a spotLight. I'm not sure what the problem is.

I uploaded the project here: https://github.com/maxibenner/threejsviewer
[image]

Comment: Also that line in the middle of the mug. That leads me to think your light isn't set up correctly, or the shadow mapsize is super small. Maybe add a THREE.SpotLightHelper? That always helps me debug light and shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring proper shadows can sometimes be difficult.

```js
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffa95c, 2)
spotLight.castShadow = true
spotLight.position.set(2,2,-2)

spotLight.angle = Math.PI * 0.1;

spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
spotLight.shadow.camera.far = 4;
spotLight.shadow.bias = - 0.002;
spotLight.shadow.mapSize.set( 1024, 1024 );
```

The idea is to move the spot light closer to the model and tighten the shadow camera's frustum as good as possible. The `bias` configuration is necessary to avoid self-shadowing artifacts. A bigger shadow map size (default is 512x512) sharpens the shadows.

As mentioned in the comment, adding an instance of `CameraHelper` to your scene is very helpful when optimizing shadows:

```js
scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( spotLight.shadow.camera ) );
```

Comment: And thank you once more! It works perfectly like that. The frustum did confuse me for a while but I think I got it now.